# Imagens em divs

Tags: html, css, imagem, layout-responsivo

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito de `divs` com `imagens` dentro, no caso, a dúvida é a seguinte:

- Se eu tenho uma `div`, com `400x400`, como faço para que uma imagem com `200x400` (ou outra resolução) caiba ocupando o tamanho total da `div`, sem distorcer a `imagem`, e sem usar o `background` do `css`

Por exemplo:

*a primeira `imagem` é como seria o resultado final, da forma como dito, o segundo é como ele fica normalmente, a `imagem` inteira é colocada na `div`, sempre sobrando espaço em branco, tanto `vertical`, como `horizontal`, sendo que a imagem deveria ser ajustada de acordo com o tamanho da `div`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A imagem que vou usar para teste tem a resolução 500x375 então eu faria da seguinte forma:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dicasdeboleiro.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Dicas-de-dribles-de-futebol-2.jpg">
```

Observe a propriedade `object-fit: cover` ela que da este efeito na imagem como se fosse um `background-size: cover` veja mais em: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Obs. Sem a propriedade `object-fit: cover` a imagem fica distorcida.

Comment: Problema é os navegadores suportados. Mas é uma boa opção quando todo o mundo deixar de usar IE.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo realmente o IE e o EDGE são um problema como sempre kkk porém esta propriedade usando prefixos já é suportada por 91.5% dos browsers no Brasil segundo http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: Chique 10 mesmo. Vou começar a utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Poderá usar o `overflow: hidden` no elemento que envolve a imagem para que a imagem fique dentro dos limites estabelecidos. E na imagem pode subtrair as margens 50% (metade de 100%), em cima e em baixo.

```css
.imagem-1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.imagem-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-bottom: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem-1">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200x400&w=200&h=400">
</div>
```